# How do I check for uncommitted git repositories in windows

Tags: git, powershell-3.0

I have an enormous, terrible pile of git repositories, both my own and those of a couple of clients, scattered over a set of directories (several other developers I work with have the same problem). I'd like to write a script that I and they can run that will iterate over a set of directories and tell us which ones have uncommitted changes. Sadly, most of the examples I've seen out there do this using bash, which may not be available on all machines (we're a windows shop). Is there a way to do this in powershell or plain old batch files?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick 'n dirty Powershell script:

```
$fn = $env:temp\gitStat.txt
$dir = dir $pwd | ?{$_.PSISContainer}  
$start = $pwd  

foreach ($d in $dir) {  
  cd $d  
  if(Test-Path $fn) {  
      Remove-Item $fn  
  }  
  & git status | Out-File $fn  
  $ss = Select-String -Path $fn -SimpleMatch "Changes not staged for commit"  
  if($ss -ne $null) {  
      $msg = [string]::Format("{0} has modified files", $pwd)  
      Write-Host $msg  
  }  
  $ss = Select-String -Path $fn -SimpleMatch "Untracked files"  
  if($ss -ne $null) {  
      $msg = [string]::Format("{0} has untracked files", $pwd)  
      Write-Host $msg  
  }  
  $ss = Select-String -Path $fn -SimpleMatch "Changes to be committed"  
  if($ss -ne $null) {  
      $msg = [string]::Format("{0} has staged files", $pwd)  
      Write-Host $msg  
  }  
  cd $start  
}
```

Here's a batch file I wrote to run under JPSoft's tcc.exe command shell.  It could probably be adapted to cmd.exe or powershell.

```
@echo off  
:  Because this needs %_cwd, it must be used with TCC.exe  
@if "%_cmdproc"=="TCC"  (goto OK)  

:testTCCLE   
@if NOT "%_cmdproc"=="TCCLE"  (goto wrongShell)  

:OK  

global /i /q /s4 (if exist .git\ echo === %_cwd === && git status)  

goto xit  

:wrongShell  
echo TCC/TCCLE required.  

:xit
```

This shows the status for each git dir; I've been working on a version that only shows dirs with uncommitted changes, but haven't finished it yet.  Another refinement will be to show dirs that are ahead or behind any repo they track.  HTH.